# Centering lines with equations while labelling each line separately

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align, amsmath, labels

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(D_{1}\cap D_{2})=\mathbb{P}(D_{1})\mathbb{P}(D_{2}),\ \mathbb{P}(D_{2}\cap D_{3})=\mathbb{P}(D_{2})\mathbb{P}(D_{3}),\ \mathbb{P}(D_{1}\cap D_{3})=\mathbb{P}(D_{1})\mathbb{P}(D_{3})\label{eq:equation}\\
(D_{1}\cap D_{2}\cap D_{3})=\mathbb{P}(D_{1})\mathbb{P}(D_{2})\mathbb{P}(D_{3}\label{eq:moreequations}
\end{align}
```

[image: equation]

When I display this, the top line of the equations is no centered over the bottom line with the single equations. How can I achieve this, without loosing my labels?

When I switch to a different approach, such as using `array` to get the centering done, I lose the capability of labelling all the lines separately.

Comment: Your 'document' has no class and  no `\end{document}` as well as no `&` character within `align`....

Answer (score 3):

`align` should only be used when there is alignment to be specified (with `&`) for unaligned equations use `gather` but here the first row is simply too wide (I would guess, as you gave no indication of page width) so you can use `split` (or better `gathered`) to spread it over three lines, with one number.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\mathbb{P}(D_{1}\cap D_{2})=\mathbb{P}(D_{1})\mathbb{P}(D_{2}),
\ \mathbb{P}(D_{2}\cap D_{3})=\mathbb{P}(D_{2})\mathbb{P}(D_{3}),
\ \mathbb{P}(D_{1}\cap D_{3})=\mathbb{P}(D_{1})\mathbb{P}(D_{3})\label{eq:equation}\\
(D_{1}\cap D_{2}\cap D_{3})=\mathbb{P}(D_{1})\mathbb{P}(D_{2})\mathbb{P}(D_{3}
\label{eq:moreequations}
\end{gather}

so
\begin{gather}
\begin{gathered}\mathbb{P}(D_{1}\cap D_{2})=\mathbb{P}(D_{1})\mathbb{P}(D_{2})\\
 \mathbb{P}(D_{2}\cap D_{3})=\mathbb{P}(D_{2})\mathbb{P}(D_{3})\\
 \mathbb{P}(D_{1}\cap D_{3})=\mathbb{P}(D_{1})\mathbb{P}(D_{3})
\end{gathered}\label{eq:equationb}\\
(D_{1}\cap D_{2}\cap D_{3})=\mathbb{P}(D_{1})\mathbb{P}(D_{2})\mathbb{P}(D_{3}
\label{eq:moreequationsb}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the first line is too wide, I suggest using a brace in order to make it clear that the number refers to all three conditions.

I recommend using a personal command, rather than repeating `\mathbb{P}` all over.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\PP}{\mathbb{P}}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\begin{cases}
  \PP(D_{1}\cap D_{2})=\PP(D_{1})\PP(D_{2}), \\
  \PP(D_{2}\cap D_{3})=\PP(D_{2})\PP(D_{3}), \\
  \PP(D_{1}\cap D_{3})=\PP(D_{1})\PP(D_{3})
\end{cases}
\label{eq:equation}\\
\PP(D_{1}\cap D_{2}\cap D_{3})=\PP(D_{1})\PP(D_{2})\PP(D_{3})
\label{eq:moreequations}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}%your class was missing
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}%for references, see below.

\DeclareMathOperator{\prob}{\mathbb{P}}% improves spacing and leads to a more consistent typography


\begin{document}
I would prefer the following layout, since it clearly shows what you refer to. 
\begin{align}
    \prob(D_{1}\cap D_{2})
        &=\prob(D_{1})\prob(D_{2}),\label{eq:equation1}\\ 
    \prob(D_{2}\cap D_{3})
        &=\prob(D_{2})\prob(D_{3}),\label{eq:equation2}\\\ 
    \prob(D_{1}\cap D_{3})
        &=\prob(D_{1})\prob(D_{3}),\label{eq:equation3}\\
    \prob(D_{1}\cap D_{2}\cap D_{3})
    &=\prob(D_{1})\prob(D_{2})\prob(D_{3}).\label{eq:moreequations}
\end{align}

Use \cref{eq:equation1,eq:equation2,eq:equation3}, \crefrange{eq:equation1}{eq:equation3}, \cref{eq:moreequations} or \eqref{eq:moreequations} for references.


An alternative: For any $1\leq i<j\leq 3$, we have
\begin{align}
    \prob(D_{i}\cap D_{j})
        &=\prob(D_{i})\prob(D_{j}),\label{eq:equation}\\ 
    \prob(D_{1}\cap D_{2}\cap D_{3}),
    &=\prob(D_{1})\prob(D_{2})\prob(D_{3}).\label{eq:moreequations2}
\end{align}
Another alternative probably would be: The events $D_1, D_2,$ and $D_3$ are statistically independent. 

\end{document}
```

There might be a few typos in your code.

[image]